# Extrapolating implied dividend yield

Tags: options, forward, dividends, implied

I have liquid option quotes for 1, 2, 3 and 4y expiries. I was able to imply the continuous dividend yield for all of those. How would you extrapolate such **implied** yield to 5 and 6y expiries?

Comment: I would take a step back and ask the usefulness of such a calculation. Are you calculating dividend yields from vanilla option prices? In practice I have found this to be a first-order approximation. Also in most instances you calculate the dividend from $(r-\delta)$ (requiring you to have some opinion as to the structure of $r$) which is increasingly difficult in the durations you mention.